# Battery usage of sencha touch 2 application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

//Hi i have developed one application in sencha touch 2 framework with the help of phonegap build.The thing is that i need to test my application so that i come to know battery usage of of my application. Can u provide some detail how to do that and whats the minimum battery consumption of a normal application .My application size is 2mb after phonegap build. Because i dont want my application drain mobile battery.

//Hey and one more thing is there any way to check battery level of mobile so that i can alert user battery is low and close application or put for mobile charge. The device itself show battery low than also i need to check.Provide me proper guidance in this.

Answer (score 1):

To warn a user of a low battery:

```
window.addEventListener("batterylow", onBatteryLow, false);

function onBatteryLow(info)
{
    alert("Battery low! Current level " + info.level + "%"); 
}
```

In terms of using "minimal battery consumption" it really depends on how efficient your coding is, how efficiently you manage resources, etc.

A good thing to remember though is always use a custom build of Sencha Touch to ensure only the the classes your project uses are being loaded. See:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building